# ssrs 2008 R2 show/hide not working on expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression, show-hide, ssrs-2008-r2

I have this problem, which I have already googled,searched on stack overflow and tried every  possible solution that I could found on the internet.

I have a table like this:

[image]

When the table is initally loaded the value are not visible and have to be toggled by Filter

After I click on the value, the dataset is filtered, and the Filter group will contain only 1 Value (the one that was selected) after the report reloads.

With an expression I made the left side look orange like the following, if only 1 value in a group exists :

[image]

Now I would like to also show the value on the right, but it does not work with all expressions i tried on text box level and/or group level :

```
=IIF(Fields!filter.BackgroundColor = "Orange" ,false,true)
=IIF(Fields!filter.BackgroundColor <> "Orange" ,true,false)
```

Can someone help Please ?

[image]

Comment: What expression do you use to change the background colour? I think you should try to use this same expression to show the value rather than using the BackgroundColor.

Comment: Already tried the following, 
=IIF(Count(Fields!value.Value) > 1,true,false)
But the problem is that then i do not see a value initially at all. its hidden. So it works kind of too good..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of trying in different ways, the only working solution was to add an extra column to my dataset called "hidden". If a filter value is the only value counted (grouped by filter) then put a 0 in the hidden field ,else 1 which results in something like :

```
 Filter Value Hidden
   A     B     1  
   A     C     1   
   B     A     0
```

After that, on the text field Hidden Value i used expression
    =CBool(Fields!hidden.value)

This Worked Great!

[image]